# Maximo REST API json formatting error

Tags: json, rest, api, maximo

When trying to GET data from this path:

```
/maxrest/rest/mbo/taskscheduler
```

I'm able to get the data in xml perfectly fine.
But when I try to convert it to JSON using this parameter:

```
/maxrest/rest/mbo/taskscheduler?_format=json
```

I get a 500 server error and a null pointer exception in my logs when it tries to convert over to json. I have gotten this to work when getting other mbo data such as person, assets, etc... but the taskscheduler mbo is giving me issues. I thought maybe there was some bad data being returned, but when i filtered it down to just return the taskname string from taskscheduler, it still threw the error. So it seems to be an issue with the taskscheduler mbo. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is the stacktrace:

```
05 Oct 2016 15:25:10:802 [ERROR] [MXServer] [CID-MXREST-73697] 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MboJSONStructure.setJSONObjectAttribute(MboJSONStructure.java:601)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MboJSONStructure.mbo2JSONObject(MboJSONStructure.java:491)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MboJSONStructure.serializeMboSetAsJSONObject(MboJSONStructure.java:294)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MboJSONStructure.serializeMboSetAsJSONObject(MboJSONStructure.java:126)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MboJSONSerializer.serializeResource(MboJSONSerializer.java:76)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MboSerializer.serialize(MboSerializer.java:274)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.BaseResourceRequestHandler.generateResponse(BaseResourceRequestHandler.java:456)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.BaseResourceRequestHandler.handleRequest(BaseResourceRequestHandler.java:343)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MaximoRestServlet.invokeRequestHandler(MaximoRestServlet.java:783)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.rest.MaximoRestServlet.doGet(MaximoRestServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
05 Oct 2016 15:25:10:802 [INFO] [MXServer] [CID-MXREST-73697] Correlated data: BEGIN HttpSessionId:cGV-jEFXtHCp2ao6aqoDkL9 RequestParams:_lid=username&_lpwd=password&_format=json UserName:username ClientIP: RequestURI:/maxrest/rest/mbo/taskscheduler ElapsedTime:63 ms  END
```

Comment: please add the stacktrace from your logfile when you get the null pointer exception.

Comment: @Jeroen Ok, I added the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

In system properties try edit `mxe.rest.mbo.defaultformat=xml` to `mxe.rest.mbo.defaultformat=json`.
You can now execute your requestion without adding `_format=json`.